# Cryptocurrency wallet create by programming and validate it?

Tags: cryptocurrency

I want to create my own cryptocurrency wallet. I know about private and public key concept which is used in the wallet but I could not understand how my wallet verified other public address? How my … wallet verified other users? How coinomi manage their wallet to store all kind of currency? Can anyone explain the full logic of wallet?

Answer (score 0):

The wallet is an application where the user can view their accounts. Think of the wallet like somebody's online banking experience.

The addresses are strings used in the transaction cryptography. The addresses involved in a transaction become part of the formula that creates a block. People who know some of the private information from this transaction (ie, the addresses/keys) can look at the block and discern the significance of their transaction (how much money moved between the sender and receiver addresses). Wallet programs hide this decoding process from cryptocurrency users so they can simply experience their balance.

If the wallet is like somebody's online banking, an address is like a check routing number. You can see multiple checking accounts from one online banking profile.

Hope this clears it up a bit!